# UI Application not loading PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I don't know why this application doesn't load my ui. I've written the exact codes that I've found on the internet but didn't get any result.

```
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys


class Receipt(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = None
        self.load_ui()
        self.load_signals()

    def load_ui(self):
        self.ui = loadUi('window.ui')
        self.show()

    def load_signals(self):
        pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
receipt = Receipt()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html):

> **PyQt5.uic.loadUi(uifile[, baseinstance=None[, package=”[,
> resource_suffix=’_rc’]]])**
>
> Load a Qt Designer .ui file and returns an instance of the user
> interface.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **uifile** – the file name or file-like object containing the
> .ui file.
>
> **baseinstance** – the optional instance of the Qt base class.
> If specified then the user interface is created in it. Otherwise a new
> instance of the base class is automatically created.
>
> **package** – the optional package that is the base package for any relative imports of
> custom widgets.

You must pass as a parameter the self instance, as I show below

```
self.ui = loadUi('window.ui', self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in `QMainWindow` as an argument to your `Receipt` class like this:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
receipt = Receipt(QMainWindow)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This should set the main window to your class and display the app when you execute it.